# Sprite Kit scene gets stuck or paused after sending app into background in iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode7, skscene

I am doing `SpriteKit` animation using XCode 7 interface builder means adding `SKNodes` and `SKActions` like rotation, move to , fade in and fade out everything through interface builder not even a single line of code for animation.

Everything works fine unless and until I send my app to the background mode. When I send app to background and launch it again animation gets paused. This issue is for iOS 8 only, it is working fine on iOS 9.

Below is the code I have used to present scene:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
        let scene = SceneClass(fileNamed: "xxxxxxxx.sks");
        self.view = SKView();

        let skView = self.view as! SKView

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene!.cockViewController = self;

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene!.scaleMode = .Fill

        scene!.view?.autoresizesSubviews = true;
        scene?.delegates = self
        skView.presentScene(scene)

    }
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a view class for your gamescene view if you do not have one, and add the following code

```
class GameSceneView : SKView
{
    func CBApplicationDidBecomeActive()
    {
    }
}
```

In interface builder,  on the view that holds the GameScene, make sure you set Class to GameSceneView

There is a bug in SKView where this function gets called with the become active notification and pauses the view.

*Note if this breaks something in iOS 9, then add a wrapper around it so that it should only be used on iOS 8

Comment: I have tried this by adding it in our GameScene class which is subclass of SKScene, but no effect. That method is not even getting called. Do I need to write some code in it or somewhere else so that it will get invoked?

Comment: you did not follow instructions,  your gamescene is attached to an SKView,  you need to make a class that extends off of SKView if you have not done so already,  I will edit my answer to reflect this

Comment: has anyone got this working in an example project ? I'm having trouble figuring this same problem out.. driving me crazy :(

Comment: Are you doing 8 or 9?

Comment: iOS 9, you may have seen in other post.. anyway looking at the original post here i can't help but wonder what is going on in cockViewController ! :)